# How to get value by a range of dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like so

[image]

And With this code I get the 5 latest values for each  domainId

```
  ;WITH grp AS 
(
   SELECT DomainId, [Date],Passed, DatabasePerformance,ServerPerformance, 
     rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
     (PARTITION BY DomainId ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
   FROM dbo.DomainDetailDataHistory H
)
  SELECT g.DomainId, g.[Date],g.Passed, g.ServerPerformance, g.DatabasePerformance
  FROM grp g
  INNER JOIN @Latest T ON T.DomainId = g.DomainId 
  WHERE rn < 7 AND t.date != g.[Date]
  ORDER BY DomainId, [Date] DESC
```

**What I Want**

Well I would like to know how many tickets were sold for each of these 5 latest rows but with the following condition:

Each of these rows come with their own date which differs.
for each date I want to check how many were sold the last 15minutes AND how many were sold the last 30mns.

Example:

I get these 5 rows for each  domainId

[image]

I want to extend the above with two columns, "soldTicketsLast15" and "soldTicketsLast30"

The date column contains all the dates I need and for each of these dates I want to go back 15 min and go back 30min to and get how many tickets were sold

Example:

```
SELECT MAX(SoldTickets) FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(minute, -15, '2016-04-12 12:10:28.2270000')

SELECT MAX(SoldTickets) FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(minute, -30, '2016-04-12 12:10:28.2270000')
```

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Why not use the between operator?

Comment: "I get these 5 rows for a given domainId".  I have no idea what your example results have to do with the query you have included.

Comment: @Erick Could you presennt a soloution? I consider my knowledge of sql fairly green.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for pointing that out, I uploaded the wrong picture. I have edited and it is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
;WITH grp AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DomainId, [Date], Passed, DatabasePerformance, ServerPerformance, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DomainId ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM dbo.DomainDetailDataHistory H
)
SELECT
    g.DomainId, g.[Date],g.Passed, g.ServerPerformance, g.DatabasePerformance
    ,A15.SoldTicketsLast15
    ,A30.SoldTicketsLast30
FROM
    grp g
    INNER JOIN @Latest T ON T.DomainId = g.DomainId
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT MAX(H.SoldTickets) - MIN(H.SoldTickets) AS SoldTicketsLast15
        FROM DomainDetailDataHistory AS H
        WHERE
            H.DomainId = g.DomainId AND
            H.[Date] >= DATEADD(minute, -15, g.[Date])
    ) AS A15
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT MAX(H.SoldTickets) - MIN(H.SoldTickets) AS SoldTicketsLast30
        FROM DomainDetailDataHistory AS H
        WHERE
            H.DomainId = g.DomainId AND
            H.[Date] >= DATEADD(minute, -30, g.[Date])
    ) AS A30
WHERE
    rn < 7
    AND T.[date] != g.[Date]
ORDER BY DomainId, [Date] DESC;
```

To make the correlated `APPLY` queries efficient there should be an appropriate index, like the following:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DomainId_Date] ON [dbo].[DomainDetailDataHistory]
(
    [DomainId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([SoldTickets])
```

This index may also help to make the main part of your query (`grp`) efficient.

Comment: Check my edits to your soloution please. After my edits this did work but It gave me a huge performance issue. The solution you presented did not include that i wanted 15 & 30min ticketsales for each given DomaInId and also I need to check min and max values for this. As I mentioned this creates a huge performance issue and I am curious if you have any Ideas to optimize this?

Comment: Performance is a separate question. Usually you need to have an appropriate index. For this `OUTER APPLY` query it seems that appropriate index will be on `(DomainID, Date) INCLUDE SoldTickets`. Also, instead of `MIN` and `MAX` it may be better to use `TOP(1)` with corresponding `ORDER BY`.

Comment: You are correct this is a separate question. However I felt that it would be spaming the forum with something that could get it's answer here. 

Would you mind editing the soloution with the index?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get the tickets sold from one of your dates (in the Date column) going back 15 minutes and 30 minutes. Assuming that you are using your DATEADD function correctly, the following should work:

```
SELECT MAX(SoldTickets) FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN [DATE] AND DATEADD(minute, -15, '2016-04-12 12:10:28.2270000') GROUP BY [SoldTickets]
```

The between operator allows you to retrieve results between two date parameters. In the SQL above, we also need a group by since you are using a GROUPING function (MAX). The group by would depend on what you want to group by but I think in your case it would be SoldTickets.

The SQL above will give you the ones between the date and 15 minutes back. You could do something similar with the 30 minutes back.

Comment: I want to extend the first code snippet with two colums m8. the last select was for example purposes. Updates to the question have been made